# Enable i2c on raspberry pi Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, raspberrypi

I'm trying to enable i2c on my raspberry pi 3B running Ubuntu 18.04 server for arm64. The standard method (using raspi-config) fails because the command cannot be found nor installed (unable to locate package raspi-config). I realize raspi-config is just a convenience feature and theoretically I could edit some files by hand, couldn't find any tutorials for doing this on Ubuntu 18.04. Is there a guide somewhere to enable i2c on a pi 3 running Ubuntu 18.04 server?

Comment: Possibly helpful - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi , or https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61905/enable-i2c-on-ubuntu-mate-raspberry-pi-3

Comment: thank you, but the second one says to use rapi-config, while the first has mention of i2c but doesn't seem to be a compete guide for enabling it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how I managed to install raspi-config on the Pi 3 B running Ubuntu 18.04 server for ARM64:

```
wget -4 https://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/r/raspi-config/raspi-config_20210604_all.deb -P /tmp
apt-get install libnewt0.52 whiptail parted triggerhappy lua5.1 alsa-utils -y
apt-get install -fy
dpkg -i /tmp/raspi-config_20210604_all.deb
```

After these commands, `raspi-config` (albeit seemingly an older version) was installed on the Raspberry Pi. It does give a warning that it's only meant to work on Raspbian, but it seems to have done the job for me. After installing `raspi-config`, I had to mount the boot partition:

```
sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /boot
```

And then use `sudo raspi-config`, following the prompts to enable i2c (in Advanced Settings->i2c). Then `ls /dev/i2c*` responds with `/dev/i2c-1`, indicating that i2c is enabled. I then managed to detect my i2C device using `sudo i2cdetect -y 1`. I found the instructions for installing raspi-config in a script [here](https://github.com/snubbegbg/install_raspi-config/blob/master/install.sh).

Comment: I installed a newer version of the package from https://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/r/raspi-config/ and it seemed to work OK. Is there an advantage to installing a 4-year-old copy at this point?

Comment: I followed instructions in the github page I linked at the end of my answer, as that was all I could find then. Perhaps what you found is a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Add the [ubuntu-pi-flavour-makers](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-pi-flavour-makers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) repository.

```bsh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-pi-flavour-makers/ppa
```

This will install the ppa and the pgp key to your apt keystore.
If you are using eoan (Ubuntu 19.10), then you need to edit `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-pi-flavour-makers-ubuntu-ppa-eoan.list` with your favorite text editor as root.

```bsh
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-pi-flavour-makers-ubuntu-ppa-eoan.list
```

Replace `eoan` with `bionic` so the file content is as shown below. Uncomment (remove the #) if you want the source code repository added, this is usually not needed unless you want to have a look at or make changes to the code.

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-pi-flavour-makers/ppa/ubuntu bionic main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-pi-flavour-makers/ppa/ubuntu bionic main
```

Then you can install the raspi-config package and all it's dependencies with the apt package manager:

```bsh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install raspi-config
```

Comment: On Bionic, this raspi-config seems busted. If you try to enable I2C, it asks you to confirm enabling SPI. If you try to enable SPI, it errors. The package is nearly two years old.

Comment: i noticed that. it seems offset by one menu entry.